# Tensorflow, multi label accuracy calculation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a multi label problem and i am trying to determine the accuracy of my model.

My model:

```py
NUM_CLASSES = 361

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IMAGE_PIXELS])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NUM_CLASSES])

# create the network
pred = conv_net( x )

# loss
cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits( pred, y_) )

# train step
train_step   = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize( cost )
```

i want to calculate the accuracy in two different ways
- % of all labels that are predicted correctly
- % of images where ALL labels are predicted correctly

unfortunately i am only able to calculate the % of all labels that are predicted correctly.

I thought this code would calculate % of images where ALL labels are predicted correctly

```py
correct_prediction = tf.equal( tf.round( pred ), tf.round( y_ ) )

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

and this code % of all labels that are predicted correctly

```py
pred_reshape = tf.reshape( pred, [ BATCH_SIZE * NUM_CLASSES, 1 ] )
y_reshape = tf.reshape( y_, [ BATCH_SIZE * NUM_CLASSES, 1 ] )

correct_prediction_all = tf.equal( tf.round( pred_reshape ), tf.round( y_reshape ) )

accuracy_all = tf.reduce_mean( tf.cast(correct_prediction_all, tf.float32 ) )
```

somehow the coherency of the labels belonging to one image is lost and i am not sure why.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe the bug in your code is in: `correct_prediction = tf.equal( tf.round( pred ), tf.round( y_ ) )`.

`pred` should be **unscaled logits** (i.e. without a final sigmoid).

Here you want to compare the output of `sigmoid(pred)` and `y_` (both in the interval `[0, 1]`) so you have to write:

```py
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(pred)), tf.round(y_))
```

---

Then to compute:

- Mean accuracy over all labels:

```py
accuracy1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

- Accuracy where all labels need to be correct:

```py
all_labels_true = tf.reduce_min(tf.cast(correct_prediction), tf.float32), 1)
accuracy2 = tf.reduce_mean(all_labels_true)
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm, do i understand correctly that the reduce_min packs all labels of one image together?

Comment: It will take the minimum of correct_prediction for each element of the batch. This minimum is 1 if all elements are 1 (ie all predictions are correct) and 0 if at least one element is False (and equal to 0)

Comment: I tried this approach, but I get the same accuracy value for each epoch: `Train accuracy: 0.984375 Test accuracy: 0.984375`. Any idea why this happens? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210520/cant-get-correct-acccuracy-for-multi-label-prediction

Comment: Excellent answer ,one confusion what would be the cost / loss function for multi label classification? Please add that in answer if you can.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul, MaMiFrea's cost function works for multi-label classification: cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits( pred, y_) )

Comment: why do you need to round the ground truth? I'm assuming my ground truth is like `[1,0,1,1]` and after rounding the sigmoid of predictions they would also become `[1,0,1,1]`?

Comment: Just following code from OP, you don't have to if your labels are already 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
# to get the mean accuracy over all labels, prediction_tensor are scaled logits (i.e. with final sigmoid layer)
correct_prediction = tf.equal( tf.round( prediction_tensor ), tf.round( ground_truth_tensor ) )
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# to get the mean accuracy where all labels need to be correct
all_labels_true = tf.reduce_min(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), 1)
accuracy2 = tf.reduce_mean(all_labels_true)
```

reference: https://gist.github.com/sbrodehl/2120a95d57963a289cc23bcfb24bee1b